# Clustering nodes with Hamming distance < 3

Tags: python, performance, graph, clustering, edit-distance

I want to speed up the following code, which is from an algorithm class.

I get a list of 200000 nodes where every node is a tuple of the length of 24 where every item is either a 1 or 0.

These items represent a graph where the distance between them is the hamming distance(number of bits that two nodes are different).

I have to run the union find algorithm on them to union all the nodes with distances <3.

Instead of computing all the distances between the nodes i am just creating all permutations of the each node which is 24*n + 576*n.

This is essentially 600*n which is better than n<sup>2</sup>.

I wrote the code and it runs unfortunately in 3 minutes. After profiling the code I got

```
 143269498 function calls in 185.193 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   47.656   47.656  183.583  183.583 ex2_big.py:18(cluster_alg)
        1    1.090    1.090  185.193  185.193 ex2_big.py:2(<module>)
  192670    0.165    0.000    0.165    0.000 ex2_big.py:39(union)
 11247652   13.388    0.000   13.388    0.000 ex2_big.py:49(find)
110327340  120.790    0.000  122.365    0.000 ex2_big.py:5(all_string_with_diff)
 14511524    1.175    0.000    1.175    0.000 ex2_big.py:6(<genexpr>)
  5000000    0.355    0.000    0.355    0.000 ex2_big.py:61(<genexpr>)
   596364    0.044    0.000    0.044    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.010    0.005    0.010    0.005 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
   200001    0.144    0.000    0.144    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
   200001    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
   993940    0.355    0.000    0.355    0.000 {range}
```

The heavy function is all_string_with_diff

The code of this function is very simple:

```
def all_string_with_diff(tup,k):
    perms = [(j for j in range(i-1,len(tup)-k+i))for i in range(1,k+1)]
    for x in product(*perms):
        l = list(tup)
        for y in x:
            if l[y] =='1':
                l[y] = '0'
            else:
                l[y] = '1'
        yield tuple(l)
```

This function is called for every node 2 times. One with k=1 and one with k=2. The length of the tuple is 24.

I write with python 3.5.
I went already over all tips given here https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips but did not find any optimization which i can apply more. 
Is there something unpythonic which I do here?

For sake of completeness the whole code is here

```
import sys
from itertools import product

def all_string_with_diff(tup,k):
    perms = [(j for j in range(i-1,len(tup)-k+i))for i in range(1,k+1)]
    for x in product(*perms):
        l = list(tup)
        for y in x:
            if l[y] =='1':
                l[y] = '0'
            else:
                l[y] = '1'
        yield tuple(l)



def cluster_alg(nodes,n):
    d = 1
    i = 0
    while d<3:
        for n1 in nodes.keys():
            i = i+1
            if i%1000 ==0:
                print(d,i)
            for n2 in all_string_with_diff(n1,d):
                if n2 in nodes:
                    r1 = find(nodes,n1)
                    r2 = find(nodes,n2)
                    if r1 != r2:
                        union(nodes, r1, r2)
                        n = n-1
        d = d+1
    return n




def union(clusters, r1, r2):
    r1 = clusters[r1]
    r2 = clusters[r2]
    if r1[1]>= r2[1]:
        r2[0] = r1[0]
        r1[1] = r1[1] + r2[1]
    else:
        r1[0] = r2[0]
        r2[1] = r2[1] + r1[1]

def find(clusters, u):
    while clusters[u][0]!= u:
        u = clusters[u][0]
    return u

nodes = {}
n = 0
for index, line in enumerate(open(sys.argv[1], 'r')):
    if index==0:
        node_data = line.strip().split(" ")
        n = int(node_data[0])
    else:
        arr = tuple(i for i in line.strip().split(" "))
        if arr in nodes:
            n = n-1
        else:
            nodes[arr] = [arr,1]


print(cluster_alg(nodes,n))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389841/efficiently-find-binary-strings-with-low-hamming-distance-in-large-set   (-1 for research) A bit harsh, but you're doing an algorithm course. It's an algorithm question and you're applying brute force? Oh to be a student again. Good luck. It's a good start.

Comment: It is intended to be a refresher. I don't want to get rusty with this subject :-). It is not really brute force. It is still O(n). because i restricted myself to a hamming distance of 3. For a bigger distance this algorithm woukd be bad because its running time is O(2^distance), but for distance 2 it is O(600*n) = O(n) which is better than O(n^2*log(n))

Comment: "This function is called for every node 2 times. One with k=0 and one with k=1." In the code I see `all_string_with_diff(n1,d)` with `1 <= d < 3`. Is it safe to assume you made a mistake in your description?

Comment: yes. sorry. This is a typo. Fixing it . Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Still fiddling around with this code, I figured that `product(*perm)` will produce values such as `(18,18)` or `(4,4)` for `k=2`; basically turning `l` back to its original value. Since it is not producing any difference with the original value, they should be skipped, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Generic comments

Your spacing is very odd and inconsistent, which makes reading the code a bit harder. 2 blank lines before function definition, spaces around operators, and after a coma is what is suggested by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

You should also put your top-level code under `if __name__ == '__main__'` to be able to import your file without anything being executed. And since local symbols are resolved faster in Python, it is also often advised to wrap the top-level code into a `main()` function and just have

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

at the end of the file.

Your naming also involves a bit of abreviations which is not really necessary.

And you also happen to `open` a file without `close`ing it. You should use the `with` statement in conjunction with `open` to avoid forgetting such things.

Other nitpicks include creating generators that will only iterate over an iterable without modification (`(j for j in range(i-1,len(tup)-k+i))` or `i for i in line.strip().split(" ")`) and using `str.strip().split(' ')` where `str.split()` would give similar results.

A first pass on your file would turn it into:

```
import sys
from itertools import product


def all_string_with_diff(tup, k):
    perms = [range(i - 1, len(tup) - k + i) for i in range(1, k + 1)]
    for x in product(*perms):
        l = list(tup)
        for y in x:
            if l[y] == '1':
                l[y] = '0'
            else:
                l[y] = '1'
        yield tuple(l)


def cluster_alg(nodes, n):
    d = 1
    i = 0
    while d < 3:
        for n1 in nodes:
            i = i + 1
            if i%1000 == 0:
                print(d, i)
            for n2 in all_string_with_diff(n1, d):
                if n2 in nodes:
                    r1 = find(nodes, n1)
                    r2 = find(nodes, n2)
                    if r1 != r2:
                        union(nodes, r1, r2)
                        n = n - 1
        d = d + 1
    return n


def union(clusters, r1, r2):
    r1 = clusters[r1]
    r2 = clusters[r2]
    if r1[1] >= r2[1]:
        r2[0] = r1[0]
        r1[1] = r1[1] + r2[1]
    else:
        r1[0] = r2[0]
        r2[1] = r2[1] + r1[1]


def find(clusters, u):
    while clusters[u][0] != u:
        u = clusters[u][0]
    return u


def build_nodes(stream):
    nodes = {}
    node_data = next(stream)
    n = int(node_data.split()[0])

    for line in stream:
        arr = tuple(line.split())
        if arr in nodes:
            n -= 1
        else:
            nodes[arr] = [arr, 1]

    return nodes, n


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    with open(filename) as f:
        nodes, n = build_nodes(f)

    print(cluster_alg(nodes, n))
```

I also changed the way you iterate over the lines in the file to simplify the special case of the first line.

## cluster_alg

`i` is only used to "monitor" that the code is alive and processing stuff. At this point you should be fairly confident that your code produce the desired results and you could remove that bit. Or at least use `for i, n1 in enumerate(nodes):`.

Same kind of argument for `d`, you do not need to manage its incrementation yourself. Use `for d in range(1, 3):` instead of your `while`.

```
def cluster_alg(nodes, n):
    for d in range(1, 3):
        for n1 in nodes:
            for n2 in all_string_with_diff(n1, d):
                if n2 in nodes:
                    r1 = find(nodes, n1)
                    r2 = find(nodes, n2)
                    if r1 != r2:
                        union(nodes, r1, r2)
                        n -= 1
    return n
```

## all_string_with_diff

I was first tempted to rewrite `perms` using:

```
size = len(tup) - k + 1
perms = [range(i, size + i) for i in range(k)]
```

as there is no need to have `i` start at 1 and then consistently substract 1 from it. But there is no real gain beside better readability.

But since you know that you will only call that function with a limited subset of values for `k` (1 and 2 in your case), why not try to provide an improved version for each value:

```
def differences_1(tup):
    for x, val in enumerate(tup):
        l = list(tup)
        l[x] = '0' if val == '1' else '1'
        yield tuple(l)


def differences_2(tup):
    for x, y in product(range(len(tup) - 1), range(1, len(tup))):
        l = list(tup)
        l[x] = '0' if l[x] == '1' else '1'
        l[y] = '0' if l[y] == '1' else '1'
        yield tuple(l)


def cluster_alg(nodes, n):
    for differences in (differences_1, differences_2):
        for n1 in nodes:
            for n2 in differences(n1):
                if n2 in nodes:
                    r1 = find(nodes, n1)
                    r2 = find(nodes, n2)
                    if r1 != r2:
                        union(nodes, r1, r2)
                        n -= 1
    return n
```

On my machine, `differences_2` is around 10% faster than `all_string_with_diff` with `k=2` for tuples of 24 elements.

## Strings vs tuples

You can gain an additionnal 5% speedup by converting between `string` and `bytearray` rather than `tuple` and `list`. This will, however, require that you adapt your parsing a bit:

```
import sys
from itertools import product


def differences_1(value):
    for x, val in enumerate(value):
        l = bytearray(value, 'utf8')
        l[x] = 48 if val == '1' else 49  # 48 is ord('0'), 49 is ord('1')
        yield l.decode()


def differences_2(value):
    for x, y in product(range(len(value) - 1), range(1, len(value))):
        l = bytearray(value, 'utf8')
        l[x] = 48 if l[x] == 49 else 49  # 48 is ord('0'), 49 is ord('1')
        l[y] = 48 if l[y] == 49 else 49  # 48 is ord('0'), 49 is ord('1')
        yield l.decode()


def cluster_alg(nodes, n):
    for differences in (differences_1, differences_2):
        for n1 in nodes:
            for n2 in differences(n1):
                if n2 in nodes:
                    r1 = find(nodes, n1)
                    r2 = find(nodes, n2)
                    if r1 != r2:
                        union(nodes, r1, r2)
                        n -= 1
    return n


def union(clusters, r1, r2):
    r1 = clusters[r1]
    r2 = clusters[r2]
    if r1[1] >= r2[1]:
        r2[0] = r1[0]
        r1[1] = r1[1] + r2[1]
    else:
        r1[0] = r2[0]
        r2[1] = r2[1] + r1[1]


def find(clusters, u):
    while clusters[u][0] != u:
        u = clusters[u][0]
    return u


def build_nodes(stream):
    nodes = {}
    node_data = next(stream)
    n = int(node_data.split()[0])

    for line in stream:
        value = ''.join(line.split())
        if value in nodes:
            n -= 1
        else:
            nodes[value] = [value, 1]

    return nodes, n


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    with open(filename) as f:
        nodes, n = build_nodes(f)

    print(cluster_alg(nodes, n))
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not quite sure why permutations of each node would help here.

how about converting each 24 bit string into an integer and handling hamming distance as a simple xor operation?